# acts-as-taggable-on tags not shown again after page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

Alright, so after wrestling with the ruby on rails plugin acts-as-taggable-on for a couple of days it has come down to this:

I have a model 'Events' and a calendar (jQuery FullCalendar) where you can click on saved events to see and edit its info. I have an input field tag_list in the edit-view where you can add tags, and I see in the server log that the tags are inserted into my sqlite3 database, and I can see them correctly in the sqlite3 console.

Right after I've saved new tags, they show up as intended in the view event-pop up, but as soon as I refresh the page (with/without cache-reload) they don't show up any more! It's driving me mad!

Here's the code:

**Model - event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :title, :presence => true
 validates :country, :presence => true

 attr_accessible :title, :country, :start, :end, :website, :fbevent, :artists, :description, :admission, :color, :tag_list

 acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

**Controller (destroy, head and end left out) events_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    render :json => Event.all
  end

  def create
    render :json => Event.create!(:start => params[:start], :end => params[:end], :title => params[:title],
        :color => params[:color], :country => params[:country], :website => params[:website],
        :fbevent => params[:fbevent], :artists => params[:artists], :description => params[:description],
        :admission => params[:admission], :tag_list => params[:tag_list])
  end

  def update
    event = Event.find(params[:id])
    event.update_attributes!(:start => params[:start], :end => params[:end],
        :title => params[:title], :color => params[:color], :country => params[:country], :website => params[:website], :fbevent => params[:fbevent], :artists => params[:artists], :description => params[:description],
        :admission => params[:admission], :tag_list => params[:tag_list])
    render :json => event
  end
```

**JavaScript application.js that sits in middle between jQuery UI input boxes and model (The Open event and Save event functions)**

```
eventClick: function(fcEvent) {
            this.eventViewNoEdit.model = this.collection.get(fcEvent.id);
            this.eventViewNoEdit.render();
        }, 
open: function() {
        this.$('#title').val(this.model.get('title'));
        this.$('#country').val(this.model.get('country'));
        this.$('#website').val(this.model.get('website'));
        this.$('#fbevent').val(this.model.get('fbevent'));
        this.$('#artists').val(this.model.get('artists'));
        this.$('#description').val(this.model.get('description'));
        this.$('#admission').val(this.model.get('admission'));
        this.$('#tag_list').val(this.model.get('tag_list'));
    },
    save: function() {
            this.model.set({'title': this.$('#title').val(), 'color': 'Blue', 'country': this.$('#country').val(), 'website': this.$('#website').val(), 'fbevent': this.$('#fbevent').val(), 'artists': this.$('#artists').val(), 'description': this.$('#description').val(), 'admission': this.$('#admission').val(), 'tag_list': this.$('#tag_list').val()});
        if (this.model.isNew()) {
            this.collection.create(this.model, {success: this.close});
        } else {
            this.model.save({}, {success: this.close});
        }
    }
```

**Relevant part of render view**

```
 <%= content_tag :div, :class =>"eventdiv" do -%>
    <%= content_tag :h2, "Tagged with" %>
    <%= content_tag :p,"", :id=> "tag_list", :class => "field" %>
  <% end -%>
```

If you have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong, please let me know :c I guess there must be something wrong where the events are loaded into the calendar so that the connection to the 'tags'-database doesn't follow, but I can't understand how it should be?

Started GET "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Feb 28 09:37:35 +0100 2012
Processing by EventsController#index as JSON
  Event Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events"
Completed 200 OK in 57ms (Views: 7.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Is what it says when I reload the page...